# Email shows time 1 hour ahead of server time

Tags: linux, outlook, time

I have a dedicated linux server.

On plesk it shows the correct local time on the server. However, for all the emails on the server for some reason show the time + 1 hour in outlook.

See screenshot beow on outlook
[image: server time is 1 hour behind]

How can I get this fixed so that 10:44 is the time on outlook rather than 11:44?

Comment: What do the "Date" headers in the emails say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to make sure both the server and client using the correct time zone, and that it's set to use/not use day light savings as would be correct for your location.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the US?  Did you update your timezone data files last year when the US government changed when DST started and ended?

Without knowing what distribution you have, I can't provide better information about how to do that, beyond suggest that you look for "zoneinfo" updates.

Comment: I am in the UK and server is set for GMT time.

Comment: Daylight savings is BST (British Standard Time)

Comment: btw - the US changes (which were largely mirrored elsewhere) were done in 2k7 .. hard to believe it's been 2.5 years since that debacle :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Time Zone settings in Outlook match those of the PC.

```
Tools >  Options > Calendar Options > Time Zone
```